# About 3.F Exercise 21 on p.114 in "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

I cannot solve 3.F Exercise 21 on p.114.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.
Let $V'$ be the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$.
Let $U^0 := \{\phi \in V' | \phi(u) = 0$ for all $u \in U\}$.

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ with $W^0 \subset U^0$.
>   Prove that $U \subset W$.

My attempt is here:

$\dim W^0 + \dim W = \dim V$
$\dim U^0 + \dim U = \dim V$

Since $W^0 \subset U^0$, $\dim W^0 \leq \dim U^0$.
So, $\dim U \leq \dim W$.

I cannot prove that $U \subset W$.

Please tell me a proof.

Comment: Sorry but What is $W^0$? Annihilator?

Comment: @ZFR $W^0 = \{\phi \in V^* | \phi(w) = 0$ for all $w \in W\}$.

Comment: HINT: note that $W^0\subset U^0$ just say that every linear functional $\varphi $ such that $W\subset \operatorname{null}\varphi $ then $U\subset \operatorname{null}\varphi $.

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you very much.

Comment: If $W =\text{null} \phi$ for some $\phi$, then $U \subset W$. But $\dim \text{null} \phi = n \text{ or } n-1$. Please give me an additional hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi_1,\dotsc,\psi_m$ be a basis of $W^0$. Extend it to $\psi_1,\dotsc,\psi_m, \psi_{m+1},\dotsc,\psi_{m+n}$ a basis of $U^0$. Extend it to $\psi_1,\dotsc,\psi_m, \psi_{m+1},\dotsc,\psi_{m+n},\psi_{m+n+1},\dotsc,\psi_{m+n+k}$ to a basis of $V'$. Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_m, v_{m+1},\dotsc,v_{m+n},v_{m+n+1},\dotsc,v_{m+n+k}$ be the "primal" basis of $V$.

Let $v\in V$ be written as
\begin{multline}
    v = a_1v_1+\dotsb+a_mv_m+a_{m+1}v_{m+1}+\dotsb+a_{m+n}v_{m+n}+\\
    a_{m+n+1}v_{m+n+1}+\dotsb+a_{m+n+k}v_{m+n+k}.
\end{multline}
If $v\in W\subset V$
\begin{equation}
    \psi_1(v)=0=a_1
\end{equation}
Similarly, using $\psi_2,\dotsc,\psi_m$, we conclude that $a_2=\dotsb=a_m=0$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
    W\ni v = a_{m+1}v_{m+1}+\dotsb+a_{m+n}v_{m+n}+a_{m+n+1}v_{m+n+1}+\dotsb+a_{m+n+k}v_{m+n+k}.
\end{equation}
If $v\in U\subset V$, we have additionally that $a_{m+1}=\dotsb=a_{m+n}=0$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
    U\ni v = a_{m+n+1}v_{m+n+1}+\dotsb+a_{m+n+k}v_{m+n+k}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, if $v\in U$, then $v\in W$. It follows that $U\subset W$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w_1, \cdots, w_m$ be a basis of $W$.
Let $w_1, \cdots, w_m, v_1, \cdots, v_n$ be a basis of $V$.
Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of $U$.

Then, we can write $u$ as $u = \alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m w_m + \beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n$ for some $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_m, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n \in \mathbb{F}$.

Let $\phi$ be an arbitrary element of $W^0(\subset U^0)$.

Then, $\phi(\beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n) = \phi(u) - \phi(\alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots, \alpha_m w_m) = 0$.

So, $\beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n = 0$ because if $\beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n \ne 0$, then we can find a $\psi \in W^0$ such that $\psi(\beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n) = 1$.

$\therefore$ $u = \alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m w_m \in W$.

Comment: I think you can find such an $\psi$ ​​if $\beta_1v_1+\cdots+\beta_nv_n$ is in $W$, but how do you prove that?

Comment: @Hopmaths I answered 3 years ago. So I cannot judge if my answer is ok or not now. lol.

Comment: Since $w_1,\dots,w_m,v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, $w_1,\dots,w_m,v_1,\dots,v_n$ is linearly independent. So, if $\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n\neq 0$ then $\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n$ is not in $W$.

Comment: So, there exists a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m,\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n,u_1,\dots,u_{n-1}$ of $V$.

Comment: Let $\psi$ be an element of $V'$ such that $w_i\mapsto 0$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n\mapsto 1$ and $u_i\mapsto 0$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Then, $\psi\in W^0$ and $\psi(\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n)=1$. In my answer, for any $\phi$ which is an element of $W^0$, $\phi(\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n)=0$. So, $\psi(\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n)=0$. This is a contradiction.